# partiially load data into Tableau from MySQL database

Tags: mysql, import, tableau-api

I have a MySQL database running and I've got Tableau connected to it. The issue I am having is that the table is too long - it contains years of transactions. And I only care about the transactions in the most recent 60 days. I have added a filter on the date so I can get the subset I need. However, it is super slow every time I open the workbook since it will query on the whole table and then apply the filter. So my question is:

How can I make Tableau only load the most recent 60 days of data to start with? Thanks!

Comment: Is the date filter you're using a data source filter, or a visualization level filter?

Comment: I was using a visualization level filter before I posted this question. Now I am using a data source filter, but it seems doesn't help with the speed. The temporary workaround I am using is to 'manually' sample some rows from the database and use the sample in Tableau. Not the simplest way I guess.

Comment: Is giving your datasource an index on the date field you care about a possibility? If table access is the bottleneck you don't have too many options inside tableau.

Comment: Thank you @Andy. It is good to get confirmation even thou the problem remains open.

Comment: what is your condition? can you post the condition that you are using in visual level or data source filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a few possible solutions :

1. Create a view or a materialised view in mySQL to cater for the last 60 days only
2. Change the sheet filter to a context filter.  The (normal) sheet filter won't affect the data query, but a context filter will.
3. If it's still too slow, create an extract.  You can schedule Tableau Server to update the extract every day.

Comment: Thank you @cmcau! Solution 1 sounds very practice and I will try it soon. I need to learn what context filter is for solution 2. And for solution 3, I only have a Tablueau desktop license, so I guess that's not feasible in my case?

Comment: Context filter is simply: right-click on a field on the filters shelf and choose "Add to Context"